# how to change the predefined Paths in the Krusader Location Toolbar button?

Tags: settings, preferences, krusader

Krusader offers quick access to a set of predefined folders with a 
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMYBz.png) on the left side of its Location Toolbar. Two of these links should be user configurable since they can be set by the user in the KDE settings (Downloads and Desktop). How can this quick link menu be changed?

I tried finding a corresponding Setting in the Toolbar preferences of Krusader, the krusaderrc file and the krusader source code. From the lack of the relevant strings in the sources and translation file its clear that they aren't hardcoded but they have to come from somewhere.